# Trying to connect to database postgres

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

This is the error I'm getting it's refusing to connect to my database

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 2, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="176.58.104.XXX",database="XXXX", user="XXXXX", password="XXXXX")
  File "c://addr", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "176.58.104.XXX" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've diagnosed as much as the reason as possible.
 my postgresql.conf files are here so I updated them all except sample

```
locate postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/postgresql.conf.sample
```

with

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = '*'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
```

And then updated pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

and restarted sudo systemctl restart postgresql

I followed these instructions https://zaiste.net/postgresql_allow_remote_connections/

But I'm still getting the error

here is my netstat -nlt and I can still see my connection bonded with 127.0.0.1

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Am I missing some step?

Comment: The `#` in front of `#listen_addresses = '*'`  means, it is **not** active, you need to remove the `#`

Comment: @  a_horse_with_no_name, it's been a long day and I was coming back here to edit the question, can't believe I missed that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the # was in front of #listen_addresses = '*' by default.

Didn't see it.